# Maintainable and extensible navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, class-diagram, domain-model, navigation-properties

Which one is better (Pros and Cons) (Maintenance, Extensibility) :

1.Has a `Request` entity have 3 different reference (navigation properties) to `Signature`:

[image]

2.Has a `Request` entity have collection of `Signature`, which each `Signature` has `Signature Type`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Model 1

This model pretty much carves your business rules in stone. There can *only* be three types of signatures and there can *only* be one each. Any change in these rules requires a database change, which is always a pervasive change.
Apart from that, there's a potential pitfall when you work with disconnected entities that you want to re-attach to a context. If one (or two) of the `Signature`s are the same (business rules permitting) you must heed the exception that two entity keys are added twice.

#### Model 2

This gives more freedom (extensibility), but that means that you need coded business rules to enforce the rules I mentioned for Model 1. On the other hand, it would allow more people to approve a request, for example.
Maybe an even better model would be to make `SignatureType` a [flagged enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx), so a signature can have multiple types and the signatures don't have to be repeated (again: the business rules permitting). This would avoid the potential multiple key exception I mentioned with Model 1.

So I would prefer model 2 (with flagged enum), because I like to express business rules in code, not in database constraints.

Comment: +1, thanks brother. `flagged enum` was a nice advice.I am using .net 4 so EF4.x doesn't support enums and needs some extra work.But why I should have `disconnected entities` that I want to re-attach to a context?

Comment: You will have disconnected entities the moment you have entities that live longer than the context, which is a very common scenario, not only in web applications.